# Module javafx.controls not found even after adding vm arguments

Tags: java, javafx, java-11, javafx-11

I want to learn to develop GUI applications with Java and JavaFX, but I'm having a really hard time setting JavaFX up.

I've seen every stackoverflow post and youtube video tutorial and i'm still getting the same error.

I've downloaded the appropriate version of the JavaFX from the gluonhq website.

I've created a user library named JavaFX11 and added all the jars that were on the javafx lib folder.

I've edited the run configurations on eclipse and added the path of the lib folder to the VM Arguments.

And I still get the error "Module javafx.controls not found".

Here is a picture of the library i created:

[image: screenshot_1]

And here is a picture of the VM Arguments:

[image: screenshot_2]

And here is the error that I'm getting:

[image: screenshot_3]

Comment: @Abra Eclipse is mentioned in the post. @victor Have you verified there"s actually anything but the META-INF entries in those jars? Maven downloads those jars with the name shown in screenshot 1 plus system dependent jars (`javafx-controls-13.0.2-win.jar` and similar on my windows machine) that actually contain class files

Comment: You should be able to inspect those jars in the dependencies part of yhr project explorer...

Comment: Is your code in a package? Do you have a `module-info.java` file in your Eclipse java project?

Comment: is this what you mean, @fabian ?

http://i.imgur.com/UryWq68.png

Comment: Did you actually use your JavaFX11 library somewhere? You have to add it to your module path. @Abra Don't confuse the Maven downloads with an installed SDK. The packaging of the jars is different.

Comment: here is my project structure/code http://i.imgur.com/8vVc1vL.png @mipa

Comment: Try following the instructions for Eclipse in the [Getting Started with JavaFX](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/) guide exactly, step-by-step. Maybe you'll see something you missed.